# rails, how to reference action mailer in jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, actionmailer

i wanted to perform an action mailer method after an ajax method completes. im building a twitter app essentially, and wanted an email notification to be sent after someone clicks 'follow', which is done asynchronously.

i gave the follow button an id

```
<%= f.submit "Follow", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary", 
        :id => "follow_button"%>
```

and then used jquery

```
$("#follow_button").bind('ajax:success', function() {

});
```

however, im really sure how i can reference my UserMailer in jquery. ultimately im trying to perform this line after my ajax is complete

```
UserMailer.is_now_following(@user, current_user).deliver
```

thanks!

hmmm i tried adding that line of code in my create function (to create the relationship of the follow) but it lags my ajax quite a lot. the ajax is to render the 'unfollow' button after the 'follow' is clicked btw.

```
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to @user}
        format.js
    end

    #UserMailer.is_now_following(@user, current_user).deliver
  end
```

i commented it out. is this what you meant for adding it after my ajax call is successful?
also, how do you put a job on queue? thanks!

Comment: Is the ajax method called by a follow click on your site or on the twitter site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better solution is doing that only in your server not in your client side.

If you do like you want you need doing 2 requests. 1 to follow people and 1 to launch mail. If you user stop this application between this 2 requests, no email is send.

The better solution is to launch your Mailer directly in your follow action. In your controller, you know if the request is a success or not. If the request is a success launch the email.

If you want more reactivity and avoid doing this job directly in your action, you can push the mailer action to a job queue.

Comment: i tried doing the solution you suggested, but it lags my ajax a lot still. am i doing it correctly? i put up the code in my post. how do you put the mailer action on a job queue? thanks!

Comment: You need put this code in a queue system like resque or delayed_job to avoid this latency

Comment: thank you! i put that line of code in a delayed_job and it doesn't lag the application at all. thank you!